# Filtering for presence multiple sub-strings in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In apps script I have an object that looks like:

```
    message_objs.push({
      'body': message.getPlainBody(),
      'date' : message.getDate(),
      'from' : message.getFrom(),
      'to' : message.getTo()

    })
```

which I am building from received emails in the inbox

I'd like to filter the emails by domain of sender so I can do:

```
var substring = 'yahoo';

var filtered =  message_objs.filter(function (obj) {
 return obj['from'].indexOf(substring)>-1;
});
```

for a single substring, but really I'd like to have an array of allowed domains like

```
var substrings = ['yahoo', 'gmail' ... ];
```

Whats the best way to do this in apps script or using ES5 tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please think of this sample script as just one of several answers. In this sample, I used `some()` for checking whether the values of `substrings` are included in `message_objs`.

#### Sample script:

```js
var message_objs = [
  {from: "sample1@sample.com"},
  {from: "sample2@yahoo.com"},
  {from: "sample3@gmail.com"},
];
var substrings = ['yahoo', 'gmail'];
var filtered =  message_objs.filter(function(obj) {
  return substrings.some(function(e) {return obj['from'].indexOf(e) > -1});
});
console.log(filtered);
```

#### Reference:

- [Array​.prototype​.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check any of them contains in the string and [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check substring presence.

```
var substrings = ['yahoo', 'gmail' ]

var filtered =  message_objs.filter(function (obj) {
   return substring.some( sub => obj['from'].includes(sub) );
});
```

---

For older browser with an additional [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
var substrings = ['yahoo', 'gmail' ]

var filtered =  message_objs.filter(function (obj) {
   return substring.filter(function(sub){
     obj['from'].indexOf(sub) > -1;
   }).length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Javascript `includes` method.

```
var substrings = ['yahoo', 'gmail' ... ];
var filtered =  message_objs.filter(function (obj) {
 return substrings.includes(obj['from']);
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think you can use includes in apps script - although that may be coming.